# Cakephp 3.x saving hasmany association

Tags: cakephp, model, save

In my project I cannot able to save hasmany associated table in a single save. My association is given as follows

### class ProductsTable extends Table

```
$this->hasMany('ProductImages', [
            'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
```

### class ProductImagesTable extends Table

```
$this->belongsTo('Products', [
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
```

In my controller the code is as follows

```
debug($this->request->data);  \src\Controller\Admin\ProductsController.php (line 81)

$product = $this->Products->patchEntity($product, $this->request->data, [
    'associated' => [ 'ProductImages']
]); 
debug($product);\src\Controller\Admin\ProductsController.php (line 86)
$this->Products->save($product);
```

### The debug result is as follows

```
 \src\Controller\Admin\ProductsController.php (line 81)

[
    'name' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor',
    'short_description' => ' Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    'description' => ' Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ',
    'sku' => 'NE132W',
    'price' => '51',
    'product_image' => [
        (int) 0 => [
            'default' => (int) 0,
            'image_name' => 'product1',
            'real_name' => '631-1478785843.png',
            'image_url' => 'http://cakephp-apps.com/mykipferl/img/Products/631-1478785843.png'
        ],
        (int) 1 => [
            'default' => '1',
            'image_name' => 'product2',
            'real_name' => '140-1478785850.png',
            'image_url' => 'http://cakephp-apps.com/mykipferl/img/Products/140-1478785850.png'
        ],
        (int) 2 => [
            'default' => (int) 0,
            'image_name' => 'product3',
            'real_name' => '416-1478785856.png',
            'image_url' => 'http://cakephp-apps.com/mykipferl/img/Products/416-1478785856.png'
        ]
    ]
]

\src\Controller\Admin\ProductsController.php (line 86)

object(App\Model\Entity\Product) {

    'name' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor',
    'short_description' => ' Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    'description' => ' Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.  ',
    'sku' => 'NE132W',
    'price' => (float) 51,
    'product_image' => [
        (int) 0 => [
            'default' => (int) 0,
            'image_name' => 'product1',
            'real_name' => '631-1478785843.png',
            'image_url' => 'http://cakephp-apps.com/mykipferl/img/Products/631-1478785843.png'
        ],
        (int) 1 => [
            'default' => '1',
            'image_name' => 'product2',
            'real_name' => '140-1478785850.png',
            'image_url' => 'http://cakephp-apps.com/mykipferl/img/Products/140-1478785850.png'
        ],
        (int) 2 => [
            'default' => (int) 0,
            'image_name' => 'product3',
            'real_name' => '416-1478785856.png',
            'image_url' => 'http://cakephp-apps.com/mykipferl/img/Products/416-1478785856.png'
        ]
    ],
    '[new]' => true,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [
        'name' => true,
        'short_description' => true,
        'description' => true,
        'sku' => true,
        'price' => true,
        'product_image' => true
    ],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[invalid]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Products'

}
```

Somebody help me for this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the appropriate property name for the association, which for `hasMany` associations is by default the plural, underscored variant of the association alias, so in your case `product_images`, not `product_image`.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Associations > HasMany Associations](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#hasmany-associations)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Saving HasMany Associations](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-hasmany-associations)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Form > Field Naming Conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#field-naming-conventions)**

Comment: Thanks for your reply, keyword 'product_images' did work for me. Also one important point (sorry its a mistake from my side) Dont use special keywords for field name in table. As you can see in my debug there is a field name "default" in product_images table which cause error. Finally my save works only when I changes the field value 'default' :)

Comment: @ndm, Does CakePHP supports auto-renewal of records for the hasMany association. Eg- I have 2 products belongs to category 1. When I edit category 1 and delete 1 product and tries to save data through categories model, will it remove product 2 from the DataBase?  
 Please have a look on my question for details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47739248/issue-is-hasmany-associated-models-data-update-modify