# Issue in hasMany associated model data update/modify

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

> ```
> I have two table,
> categories     hasMany products
> id
> name
> active
>
> products       belongsTo categories
> id
> name
> category_id
> active
> ```

When I am editing the categories, in the same time I am also displaying the Products related to the category so that I can update/modify products related to the category.

Issue:- When I add more products for the category that works fine but when I remove some products from the category,the removed product does not get deleted from the database. So I want to know that This functionality is supported by CakePHP or not. If yes please help me to find where I am going wrong.

Here is the save code:-

```
$categoryProducts = $this->Categories->get(1, [
   'contain' => 'Products' 
]);

    if($this->request->is['post', 'put']){
       $entity = $this->Categories->patchEntity($categoryProducts, $this->request->data);


      $this->Categories->save($entity);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set up your hasMany relationship, add `'saveStrategy' => 'replace'`. See the [hasMany section of the manual](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#hasmany-associations) for details.